# Where is docker registry:2 storing images on host

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I am aware that you can use `curl <registry name>:5009/v2/_catalog` to list images.

From this:
https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#storage-customization

Is is stated "By default, the registry stores its data on the local filesystem", but where is that. -I am running Docker For Mac?

I just want an easy way to delete local images, and maybe it is a matter of finding this default host location - yes I looks like I could just use a custom volume.

I am still curious to where this default storage is located.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is is stated "By default, the registry stores its data on the local filesystem", but where is that. -I am running Docker For Mac?

By default inside the container it's at `/var/lib/registry`. Each container gets its own read/write layer as part of the overlay filesystem (all of the image layers are read-only). This is stored within `/var/lib/docker` on the docker host, probably under a container or overlay sub directory, and then under a unique directory name per container. And then that, within Docker Desktop on Mac, is within a VM. You could probably exec into the container to see this path, but I wouldn't recommend modifying the contents directly for your request.

---

> I just want an easy way to delete local images, and maybe it is a matter of finding this default host location - yes I looks like I could just use a custom volume.

First, just to verify you mean deleting images in the registry and not on the local docker engine. If the latter, you can run `docker image prune`.

Assuming you have a need to run a registry server, you'll want to pass the setting `REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true` to the registry (as an environment variable, or by setting the associated yaml config). Then you can call the manifest delete API. You'll want to get the digest and then call

```
curl -X DELETE http://<registry>:5000/v2/<repo>/manifests/<digest>
```

Once that's done, you need to run a [garbage collection](https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/) on the registry while no writes are occurring (by setting the server to read-only, picking an idle time, or stopping the registry and running a separate container against the same volume):

```
docker exec registry /bin/registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml --delete-untagged
```

For simplifying the API calls, I've got a [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) project that includes `regctl image delete ...` and `regctl tag delete ...` (the latter only deleting one tag even if the manifest is referenced multiple times). And if you want to automate a cleanup policy, there's `regclient/regbot` in that same project that lets you define your own cleanup policy.

Answer (score 3):

By default the registry container keep the data in `/var/lib/registry` within the container. You can bind mount a local directory on your host like the example did `-v /mnt/registry:/var/lib/registry`; which in this case the data will be kept on your host at /mnt/registry. You can also pre-create a volume like `docker volume create registry` and bind `-v registry:/var/lib/registry`; which in this case data will be stored at `/var/lib/docker/volumes` on your host.